# Ionic3 - How to change color and size default tab bar

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 and angular. I want to change color and size of default tab bar in ionic, but when I modified main.css file, it can build success, but when I re-build, it seem return default status...

I don't know how to create new file css to change it.. How to can change new style of tab bar in ionic 3?

I'm so sorry because this is basic question, I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

I am believing that you are asking for the [tabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) in ionic

It depends whether you are building for android or ios.

If you want  to change for Android,

just add `$tabs-md-background: color($colors, custom);` in `variable.scss` file.

Where `custom` is your customized colour.
Similarly, you can change the size as well, depending on your phone os.

Comment: Hi Kevin I would like to know more about change tab properties. But in the above link I can't find changing background color

Comment: Changing the background color of what exactly? The tabs?